# tcl shell through apache

Tags: apache, web-applications, cgi, tcl

I have a tool which supports interactive queries though tcl shell. I want to create a web application through which users can send different queries to the tool. I have done some basic programming using Apache web server and cgi scripts, but i am unable to think of a way to keep the shell alive and send queries to that.

Some more information:

Let me describe it more. Tool builds a graph data structure, after building users can query for information using tcl shell, something like get all child nodes of a particular node. I cannot build the data structure with every query because building takes lot of time. I want to build the data structure and somehow keep the shell alive. Apache server should send all the queries to that shell and return the responses back to the user

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create a daemon process, perhaps using expect, that spawns your interactive program. The daemon program could listen to queries over TCP using Tcl's [socket](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/socket.htm) command. Your CGI program would create a client socket to talk to the daemopn.

Answer (score 2):

I'd embed the graph-managing program into an interpreter that's also running a small webserver (e.g., [tclhttpd](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2085), though that's not the only option) and have the rest of the world interact with the graph through RESTful web accesses. This could then be integrated behind Apache in any way you like — a CGI thunk would work, or you could do request forwarding, or you could write some server-side code to do it (there's many options there!) — or you could even just let clients connect directly. Many options would work.

Comment: FWIW, it took me about an hour of tinkering to get such a thing working in one of my projects. (I was using another embeddable webserver called Wibble; it's not a perfect choice for others though, as it depends on Tcl 8.6 which is still beta.)

Answer (score 1):

The question appears to be incomplete as you did not specify what exactly does "interactive" mean with regard to your tool.

How does it support interactive queries? Does it call `gets` in a kind of endless loop and processed each line as it's read?  If so, the solution to your problem is simple: the Tcl shell is not really concerned about whether its standard input is connected to an interactive terminal or not. So just spawn your tool in your CGI request handling code, write the user's query to that process's stdin stream, *flush it* and then read all the text written by that process to its stdout and stderr streams.  Then send them back to the browser.  How exactly to spawn the process and communicate with it via its standard streams heavily depends on your CGI code.

If you don't get the idea, try writing your query to a file and then do comething like

```
$ tclsh /path/to/your/tool/script.tcl </path/to/the/query.file
```

and you should have the tool to respond in a usual way.

If the interaction is carried using some other way in your tool, then you probably have to split it to a "core" and "front-end" parts so that the core just reads queries and outputs results, and the front-end part carries out interaction.  Then hook up that core to your CGI processing code in a way outlined above.